# System.StackOverflowException in Indexer c#

Tags: c#, .net, indexer

```
MyDict m = new MyDict();
m.Add("a", "a");
string s = m["a"]; // Getting exception here
```

Below is implementation of Indexer

```
public class MyDict: Dictionary<string,string>
{
    public string this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
             return this[key];
        }
        set
        {
            this[key] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Exception :**

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' 
occurred in ConsoleApplication2.exe
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your indexer is recursively calling itself, that's why you get `StackOverflowException` exception.

You can fix it by the following:

```
public class MyDict: Dictionary<string,string>
{
    public string this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
             return base[key];
        }
        set
        {
            base[key] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

But, it doesn't makes sense for me. *You can completely remove the indexer as base class already provides you one with the same implementation*.

Also note that you'll get a warning `'YourNameSpace.MyDict.this[string]' hides inherited member 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>.this[string]'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.`. Pay attention to those warnings :)

Comment: It's worth emphasizing that, as it stands, the overriden indexer is unnecessary, and can be removed entirely.

Comment: You mentioned it, and then provided an example where it's included anyway. To me that hid the point that it's unnecessary, so I just wanted to clarify :)

Answer (score 2):

`m["a"]` calls `this[key]` which calls `this[key]` recursively, that's why you're getting the issue.

You need to make your get/set methods reference an internal dictionary (or something similar)